# Chrome doesn't respect table cell width

Tags: google-chrome, css-tables

I have a pretty nested structure of tables from a CMS. Each column has a specified width e.g. `width="61"` for the first column.
Nevertheless Chrome ignores the width and adds random spacing so none of the columns have the right width in the end and it looks like this:

[image]

Other browsers display the code just fine.
I have tried to use `table-layout: fixed` but that made everything worse.

Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xv8U5/

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a difference of rules depending on the browser. Most browser will scale the TD to the largest TD of the same column. Chrome, however, seems to use the first TD's width as column width.

Hence, if you specify the width of a TD after the first row, that width will be ignored if the first row already contained a TD for that column.

The solution is to specify the width right from the first row.